# Ubuntu 18.04 problem: Wifi disconnects after a few seconds

Tags: networking, wireless

I am experiencing this problem the last few days - needless to say how annoying it is!
When I restart the laptop, the connection seems to be working for the first few seconds (approx < 1/2 min) but then my wifi icon on the toolbar turns to ? and all internet connectivity is gone (I also cannot access the router page).

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with Windows 10 and the wifi seems to be working normally on Windows, so it doesn't seem to be some kind of hardware issue.

Update: The output of `dmesg | tail -30`

```
[   89.947959] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 9/9
[   89.947960] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[   89.947960] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x1000000
[   89.947961] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: 0:b: disabled by eeprom
[  130.676731] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: stopping RX ring 0
[  130.676738] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0xffffffff -> 0xffffefff)
[  130.676744] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: stopping TX ring 0
[  130.676750] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0xffffffff -> 0xfffffffe)
[  130.676752] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: control channel stopped
[  130.676820] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: freeing RX ring 0
[  130.676825] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: freeing TX ring 0
[  130.676832] thunderbolt 0000:08:00.0: shutdown
[  130.677389] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
[  130.677434] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3e] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  130.677450] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  130.677451] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  130.677454] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  130.677455] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  141.191707] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  146.396090] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0
[ 1961.942132] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 1961.945143] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 1962.055601] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1966.931319] wlp2s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
[ 1966.971413] wlp2s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  (try 1/3)
[ 1966.991945] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1966.996031] wlp2s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  (try 1/3)
[ 1967.041184] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
[ 1967.043496] wlp2s0: associated
[ 1967.073448] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

Update2: There seems to be an interference with a bluetooth device I am using. Recently I connected an Apple keyboard and it was when the problems started appearing. Now I shut off the bluetooth, restarted wifi and works again. I should also note here that my bluetooth speaker is connected at the moment, but does not cause any problems. Only the apple keyboard does.. :S

Here's the new log:

```
[ 1967.073448] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 2311.498301] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 2316.508055] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0
[ 2362.817902] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 2362.821008] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 2362.940476] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 2367.820609] wlp2s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[ 2367.860785] wlp2s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[ 2367.881334] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 2367.884027] wlp2s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[ 2367.929172] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
[ 2367.931656] wlp2s0: associated
[ 2367.961039] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 3170.274053] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3188.189904] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3204.317937] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3209.383400] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[ 3209.383414] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 3228.125945] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3244.257944] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3266.269929] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3283.165976] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3300.317942] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3310.301959] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3327.197967] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3343.325939] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3359.197945] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3368.480842] input: yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy as /devices/virtual/input/input15
[ 3378.141901] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3394.269966] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3402.269700] hid-generic XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 3402.269787] input: Antonios Minas Krasakis’s Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:5/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input16
[ 3402.270096] hid-generic XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Keyboard [Antonios Minas Krasakis’s Keyboard] on zz:zz:zz:zz:zz
[ 3412.189924] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3428.317897] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3444.190954] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

Comment: check your log, and see what was the error message - either by `dmesg | tail -30` or `tail -30 /var/log/syslog` right after it is disconnected.

Comment: I just updated my original post ^^

Comment: `[ 1967.073448] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready` from this, it looks your connection is working - how do you know it is disconnected?

Comment: Just updated again. the bluetooth keyboard seems to be causing those issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently as I mentioned in the edits, my problem stemmed from an interference between the Apple bluetooth keyboard and my wifi. Changing the channels or the frequency (2.4/5GHz) of the router did not help.

What solved the problem was pairing again the bluetooth keyboard, but not through the GUI. Instead I used the guide provided [here](http://freewisdoms.com/apple-wireless-keyboard-on-ubuntu/) and now it works perfect!

Answer (score 5):

If nothing works, I'd recommend reading what is described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298857/ubuntu-wifi-connects-and-works-for-5-minutes-then-stops-working-while-remaining) with special attention to Docker: It's possible that a Docker network (bridge) configuration is actually in a [conflicting state](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/fixing-docker-and-vpn-ip-address-conflicts) with the host network, as explained in [this Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-access-internet-after-installing-docker-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-machine/53416). If you believe this is the case for you, a potential fix consists of opening a terminal and executing the following command:

```
docker network prune
```

Which will remove all custom networks not used by at least one container, as the option implies.

Comment: Many many many thanks. You save my week.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had this issue in a hotel wifi and thought I couldn't use my laptop for over a week!

Comment: Thanks, saved the day